# Adding price field to both products and order_details tables

Tags: database-design

Products in the **Products** table have a price field. However, there are times when I need to change the product price for just one order. I wanted to ask if what I did is an acceptable practice in database design.

I simply made a **price** attribute in the **Order_details** table. So when you choose a product in **Order_details**, I will programmatically have the price value be taken from the "price" field in "**Products**" (so yes, it will be a duplicate value in the database thus maybe going against some form of normalization) but my logic is that since it's a separate field in **Order_details**, I now have the option to change the price value for that particular order, which otherwise I don't see how this can be done.

[image]

Comment: prices keep changing. very rapidly. usually each product has prices table with time periods in it

Comment: My prices change every 2-3 years so that's not an issue and I wouldn't need a time period. I only need an option to change the price for a particular one time sale.

Comment: make it nullable. let it be "special_price_if_is", like "discount" filed you have. Or if you expect orders to be able to have different various attributes, you can make a json field or array

Comment: @van This seems like a kill. Every time I would need to query a report, I would need an IF statement to ask if that special price field is NOT NULL and only then use it's value, and if it is NULL, take the value from PRODUCTS table. With MY way, although duplicating a value, the price field in Order_details will ALWAYS be correct and I can always refer just to it, for anything. Your thoughts?

Comment: two sources of truth in db is always painful. joining products to check against original price will be costy for massive selects only. like reports. but in this case you  probably will need it anyway to check if prices differ... and json - don't you want a single json object in one column with all "extra" order attributes?..

Comment: I had to Google Json and the information is vast so I need to ask in order to know what to research, is Json javascript? Is it a field in an SQL query? Can you give me a link to look this up? Or are you just talking about a look-up table or does that have nothing to do with Json

Comment: I meant json as data type. What db you plan to use?

Comment: ah, ok. SQL db. I think it's only supported in version 2016 and I use 2012

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `price` field in `Order_details` is perfectly fine. In your previous design, you couldn't change the current offer prices in the `Products` table without affecting previous orders' selling prices, which was a problem. For the same reason, don't make it nullable to default to the current product price.

In general, take care when you mix tables that represent current data with tables that represent dated data.